Как преобразовать std::wstring в const char*
Этот код, сохраняет пути всех файлов из директории в векторе, дальше есть функция которая должна принимать этот путь, но проблема в том что она принимает const char*, а в векторе сохраняется std::wstring
std::vector<std::wstring> fileList;
for (const fs::path& it : fs::directory_iterator("C:\\Users\\tpog\\Documents\\images")) {
    if (fs::is_regular_file(it) && (it.extension() == ".png")) {
        fileList.emplace_back(it.c_str());

    }
}

фото кода прилагаю


А что мешает объявить его как std::vector<std::string> fileList;?

Я просто, новичок и для меня все эти векторы и функции в новинку.

попытался использовать vector std::vectorstd::string fileList; Выдало ошибку:                                no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list

тут написано, как преобразовать в std::string utf8, а дальше std::string::c_str(): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358870/convert-wstring-to-string-encoded-in-utf-8

Для начала определись ты собираешься использовать кодировки wide или всё-же ansi? Если у тебя нету прям жесткой необходимости в мультиязычности отключи в компиляторе UNICODE, тебе это сэкономит кучу времени и нервов. И вопрос отвалится сам собой.
Ну или ознакомься вот с этим ответом на aнгл. StackOverflow там https://stackoverflow.com/a/23691253/7316806 по сути и поясняют как конвертировать и почему.
Ps: unsigned char * имеет тот-же тип что и uint8_t *.
Pss: Почитай почему звёздочка ставится перед значением именно unsigned char *data с первого взгляда одинаково, но есть разница в понимании.
